# How to convert this dynamic query to normal sql query

Tags: sql-server

How to convert this dynamic query to normal sql query

```
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT  DelayId, DelayCategory, DelayReason FROM [TAMS].[DelayMaintenance] WHERE IsUtilized = 1 AND ' + @CHECKPOINTTYPE + ' = ' + CAST(1 AS CHAR(1)) + 
       ' union      SELECT 0, NULL, ''--- Pick One----'' ORDER BY DelayId'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: That depends on the value of `@CHECKPOINTTYPE` - is it a scalar value or a column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are a limited number of potential columns names, you can do:

```
SELECT *
from MyTable
where CASE @CHECKPOINTTYPE
    WHEN 'Column1' THEN Column1
    WHEN 'Column2' THEN Column2
    ELSE NULL
  END = 1
```

Otherwise you could build the query in a server-side language before passing to SQL Server, which is pretty much the same solution as you are already using.

Comment: Can you please change above my query

Comment: I think my example is pretty clear - and without knowing the column names, no I can't.

Comment: Column Names are `TRUCK`, `RAIL` and `BARGE`

Comment: OK, great! Why don't you give it a try, and I'll take a look at what you've done.

Comment: Tried that please see my answer posted

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this

```
SELECT  DelayId, DelayCategory, DelayReason
    FROM [TAMS].[DelayMaintenance]
    WHERE CASE @CHECKPOINTTYPE
        WHEN 'TRUCK' THEN Truck
        WHEN 'RAIL' THEN RAIL
        WHEN 'BARGE' THEN BARGE
        ELSE NULL
      END = 1
      AND IsUtilized = 1
    union      SELECT 0, NULL, '--- Pick One----' ORDER BY DelayId
```